# Using a Library Project

Tags: android, library-project

I have a android application, say 'OldApp', which uses some native methods within itself, and I have to use it as a library for a new app, say 'NewApp'.

This is the first time i work with this request and i have a doubt:

the OldApp has some classes, and one of these is the JNI Wrapper and contains the native methods, for example:

```
public class LibOldApp {

   private static native int method1();
   ....
   ....
}
```

Can i use all the classes/methods of the OldApp or only the wrapper, and native methods?

thank you..

Comment: Did you try using? Why not try it and let others know if it works or if you have a problem then post a question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure you can use. 
just use your old app as library for your new project.